# Baixar todos os arquivos de um diretório FTP remoto

Tags: c#, ftp

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês pois estou fazendo uma aplicação que faz download de arquivos de um diretório ftp remoto.

Poderiam passar o código para implementar em C# por favor?

Conectar ao FTP remoto e copiar todos os arquivos do diretório para uma pasta local no computador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer, quando não se precisa de tanto controle específico para esse protocolo, é utilizar a classe [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuario", "senha");
client.DownloadFile("ftp://ftp.servidor.com/caminho/arquivo.zip", @"C:\caminho\arquivolocal.zip");
```

O `WebClient` vai funcionar como deveria para essa operação. Funciona para *uploading* também, utilizando o método [`WebClient.UploadFile(String, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Se quer ter um controle maior e operações específicas do protocolo FTP, utilize a classe [`FtpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx).

A partir disso, você consegue baixar um arquivo do diretório remoto. Você quer baixar o diretório inteiro. Basta listar os arquivos que existem nesse diretório e fazer download utilizando o `WebClient.DownloadFile(String, String)` ou equivalente. Para [listar o conteúdo de um diretório remoto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms229716(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

            Console.WriteLine("Directory List Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```