# Aplicação para baixar todos os arquivos de um diretorio em FTP remoto

Tags: c#, ftp

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação tipo instalador para um sistema proprietário.

O processo que ele faz é: cria um diretório e dois subdiretórios em um PC que vai utilizar o sistema.

Depois de criar o diretorio e os subdiretorios, a aplicação acessa o ftp e baixa os executaveis que estão no ftp para os subdiretorios que estão na maquina.

O codigo que estou usando é o seguinte:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App_Install_Golden_Premium
{
    public partial class frmInstala : Form
    {
        public frmInstala()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btInstalar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string diretorio = @"C:\Program Files\Teste\";
            string subdiretorio;
            string diretorioFTP = string.Empty;
            string usuario;
            string senha;
            string arquivo = string.Empty;
            var pathWithEnv = @"%USERPROFILE%\Área de Trabalho";
            var filePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(pathWithEnv);
            string dirDesktop = filePath;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;


            // Pega dominio/usuario logado atual
            string informacao = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; ;

            if (rbGolden.Checked)
            {
                subdiretorio = "Golden";
                diretorioFTP = "ftp://ftp.ftp remoto";
                usuario = "usuario";
                senha = "senha";
            }
            else
            {
                subdiretorio = "Premium";
                diretorioFTP = "ftp://ftp.ftp remoto";
                usuario = "usuario";
                senha = "senha";
            }

            diretorio += subdiretorio;

            if (Directory.Exists(diretorio))
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("O Diretório já existe!\n- Se deseja SAIR, Clique em [CANCELAR]\n- Se deseja CONTINUAR, Clique em [REPETIR] ", "Criação de Diretorio", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Hand) == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(diretorio);

                DirectorySecurity regras = new DirectorySecurity();
                regras.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(informacao, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

                MessageBox.Show("Diretório Criado com Sucesso!", "Criação de Diretório", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(diretorioFTP);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(diretorioFTP);

            progressBar1.Maximum = di.GetFiles().Length;

            foreach( var item in di.GetFiles())
            {
                arquivo = Path.Combine(diretorio, item.Name);
                File.Copy(item.FullName, arquivo);
                lblStatus.Refresh();
                progressBar1.Value++;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Instalação efetuada com sucesso!", "Aviso",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            lblStatus.Visible = false;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Sendo que está exibindo erro nesta linha

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(diretorioFTP);
```

E o erro em questão é este:

> ```
> System.NotSupportedException não foi manipulada
> HResult=-2146233067
> Message=Não há suporte para o formato do caminho dado.
> Source=mscorlib
> StackTrace: em System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
>    em System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Init(String path, Boolean checkHost)
>    em System.IO.DirectoryInfo..ctor(String path)
>    em App_Install_Golden_Premium.frmInstala.btInstalar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) na D:\Fabio\Visual Studio\Projeto Golden Premium Download e instalacao\Instalador_golden_premium\App_Install_Golden_Premium\App_Install_Golden_Premium\frmInstala.cs:linha 78
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>    em System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>    em App_Install_Golden_Premium.Program.Main() na D:\Fabio\Visual Studio\Projeto Golden Premium Download e instalacao\Instalador_golden_premium\App_Install_Golden_Premium\App_Install_Golden_Premium\Program.cs:linha 19
>    em System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>    em System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>    em Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>    em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>    em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>    em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>    em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>    em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
> InnerException:
> ```

Comment: Vai depender do item que estiver marcado, dai ele preenche com o diretorio do nosso ftp ao qual temos dois caminhos diferentes.

Comment: DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(diretorioFTP);

Comment: Pelo que entendo de sua pergunta, voce quer saber o que está na variavel quando o erro aparece.. é isso ? se for isso é o caminho do ftp ao qual existem os executáveis a serem baixados. Se não for isso peço perdão por não entender o que está perguntando.

Comment: o caminho que preenhce é este: "ftp://ftp.cetec.santamonicace.com.br/Producao/Executaveis/"

Comment: O `DirectoryInfo` não aceita caminhos FTP ou HTTP, somente locais. Tem que achar uma outra forma de fazer o que vc quer ali.

Comment: Entendi.... mas em um todo o que estou querendo fazer está correto ?

Comment: Na visão panorâmica que tenho, sua lógica está correta. Mas precisa achar uma outra forma de baixar os arquivos e fazer sua barra de progresso sem utilizar o `DirectoryInfo`. [Aqui eu dei um exemplo de como utilizar o `WebClient` para baixar um arquivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/255515/41056), dê uma olhada lá